# How to call Dot NET method with parameters by MULE DotNet connector?

Tags: mule

I am trying to call .Net method from my ESB Mule project.
I created the following class in VS 2013:

```
namespace NicePerform.ESBDataResolver
{
    public class DataResolver
    {
        public Object InitInfrastructure(string sysAdminURL, string delimiter, int refreshIntervalInMin)
       {
         /// do something
       }
    }
}

In the Mule project I configured DotNet connector.
<dotnet:config name="DotNet_Connector" assemblyType="NicePerform.ESBDataResolver.DataResolver, NicePerform.ESBDataResolver" assemblyPath="D:\tfs\NGA\Splash\ESB\Debug\NicePerform.ESBDataResolver.dll" scope="Singleton" doc:name="DotNet Connector"/>
<dotnet:execute config-ref="DotNet_Connector" methodName="InitInfrastructure(System.String sysAdminURL, System.String delimiter, System.Int32 refreshIntervalInMin)" doc:name="DotNet Connector"/>
```

I am filling the payload:

```
{"sysAdminURL":"${sysAdmin}","delimiter":"${delimiter}","refreshIntervalInMin":"${userAdminRefreshInterval}"}
```

But on call .net method I am failing with the following exception:

```
System.Exception: Error looking for method named InitInfrastructure(System.String sysAdminURL, System.String delimiter, System.Int32 refreshIntervalInMin) : The method name InitInfrastructure(System.String sysAdminURL, System.String delimiter, System.Int32 refreshIntervalInMin) doesn't exist

Server stack trace: 
   at Org.Mule.Api.Component.ComponentLoader.MethodLookUp(Object component, String methodName, MuleMessage message)
   at Org.Mule.Api.Component.ComponentLoader.ExecuteComponent(String assembly, String type, String methodName, MuleMessage message, Boolean isSingleton)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Org.Mule.Api.Component.ComponentLoader.ExecuteComponent(String assembly, String type, String methodName, MuleMessage message, Boolean isSingleton)
   at Org.Mule.Api.Component.ComponentManager.Execute(String assembly, String typeName, String methodName, MuleMessage message, Boolean isSingleton)
   at Org.Mule.Api.Routing.Router.Process(ProcessRequest request)
   at Org.Mule.Api.Routing.__Router.Process0(IntPtr __envp, JniLocalHandle __obj, JniLocalHandle request)
```

I try to set namespace together with method name with no success. If I am changing calling method signature to receive single string parameter - it works. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct to me, but I dont have examplecode setup for it.

You mention that you have tested with setting the namespace with the method name. have you also tested the Classname together with the method name or both?

In C# int is equal to System.Int32, and I assume this doesnt cause the issue, but it might be related.

In the example files with the connector they use a slightly different notation for the methodName field: . Since we cant find an issue in your code, you could just as well try a few other ways of calling it.